# How To Download A Chrome Extension From Chrome Dashboard?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I want to download my uploaded .zip file to chrome dashboard to my PC.

Recently, my hard disks went under a major unrecoverable crash and I lost all my data (no backup, I know I'm stupid)
I also lost code for the extension. But I've uploaded it on chrome dashboard but don't find any way to download it. Is there any way to download it without publishing? Here's my dashboard screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on "More info" at the right, then click on the "main.crx" link at Download.

[image]

Comment: Mine is not published. Draft plugins don't have this option. But I've published it now. Thanks it worked :)